# Qt - qmake INSTALL only works for debug configuration

Tags: c++, qt, windows-10, 64-bit, qmake

When building my project i want [qt](/questions/tagged/qt) to copy the appropriate [dll](/questions/tagged/dll) files of [opencv](/questions/tagged/opencv) depending on the build, either `profile`/`release` or `debug`.

For now i have the following first approach in my `.pro` file:

```
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
    OPENCV_PATH = $$OUT_PWD/debug
    OPENCV_DLLS += $$files("$$PWD/../../opencv-build/install/x64/vc15/bin/*d.dll", true)
    LIBS += $$files("$$PWD/../../opencv-build/install/x64/vc15/lib/*d.lib", false)
    message(debug build!)
} else {
    OPENCV_PATH = $$OUT_PWD/release
    OPENCV_DLLS += $$files("$$PWD/../../opencv-build/install/x64/vc15/bin/*.dll", true)
    LIBS += $$files("$$PWD/../../opencv-build/install/x64/vc15/lib/*.lib", false)
    message(release build!)
}

opencv.files += $$OPENCV_DLLS
opencv.path = $$OPENCV_PATH

INSTALLS += opencv
```

When running qmake or changing the deployment i allways get the correct `Project MESSAGE` which is `debug build!` when debug build is set and `release build!` when release build is set.

But the corresponding dll files only get copied in debug build.

**So how can I get Qt to allways copy the corresponding dll files?**

Your approach can also include a full distinction between opencv's debug and release dll's since this is the ultimate goal...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add the `install` command as a build step:

[image]

Now all [dll](/questions/tagged/dll) files get copied.

Comment: You need not put update to your question as an answer, edit your post and add the update

Comment: @MohammadKanan It's not an update but an ANSWER! Did you even read what i  have written?